# SQL - Multiple conditionals with row_number()

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
+------------+------------------+-------+-----------------+------------------------------+
| product_id |       date       | STOCK | REAL_STOCK-DIFF |      Couting one time?       |
+------------+------------------+-------+-----------------+------------------------------+
| 1ab7       | 10/18/2022 18:30 |  6009 |             495 | 495                          |
| 1ab7       | 10/18/2022 20:10 |  6003 |             495 | 0                            |
| 1ab7       | 10/20/2022 10:05 |  5514 |             495 | 0                            |
| 1ab7       | 10/20/2022 11:05 | 23856 |               0 | 0                            |
| 1ab7       | 10/20/2022 12:05 | 25850 |               0 | 0                            |
| 1ab7       | 10/20/2022 13:05 | 44160 |               0 | 0                            |
| 1ab7       | 10/20/2022 14:05 | 48205 |             130 | 130                          |
| 1ab7       | 10/20/2022 17:05 | 48122 |             130 | 0                            |
| 1ab7       | 10/20/2022 18:05 | 48075 |             130 | 0                            |
| 1ab7       | 10/20/2022 19:05 | 17438 |             128 | 128                          |
| 1ab7       | 10/21/2022 1:38  | 17310 |             128 | 0                            |
| 2ab7       | 10/18/2022 18:30 | 85692 |               0 | 0                            |
| 2ab7       | 10/20/2022 14:05 | 84498 |                 | SUM DIF STOCK == 495+130+128 |
| 2ab7       | 10/20/2022 15:05 | 84477 |                 |                              |
| 2ab7       | 10/20/2022 16:05 |     0 |                 |                              |
| 2ab7       | 10/20/2022 23:38 |     0 |                 |                              |
| 2ab7       | 10/21/2022 0:05  |     0 |                 |                              |
+------------+------------------+-------+-----------------+------------------------------+
```

This data shows the select that I tried to do with partition by in SQL, I'm controlling the stock and I have to show the stock difference over the products. That said, I was doing something like partition by max - min, however several conditions are applied, like: The stock can suddenly grow or decrease and even be removed completely (stock = 0), the partition by clause won't solve it purely.

My real stock is the third column "STOCK" in black, as you can see it was dropping from 6009 to the minimum 5514, then it grew up to 23856 until 48205, then was deducted to 17438.

Here we could do something like if 23856 > last number (5514) then new minimum and maximum = 23856, Just don't know how to partition it though. For the 17438, something like if the previous row_number > 17438*1.2 (20%) then new minimum = 17438

The SQL that I made was giving me the "Dif_Stock" column, which is wrongly displaying 42691 as the difference.

All that I'm trying to do is achieve the values that I inserted here in this column "Couting one time?":
"SUM DIF STOCK == 495+130+128"

My SQL code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       product_id,
       date,
       stock,
       MaxStock,
       MinStock,
       (MaxStock - MinStock) AS Dif_Stock
FROM (SELECT product_id,
             date,
             stock,
             MAX(stock) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id) AS MaxStock,
             MIN(stock) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id) AS MinStock,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY product_id) AS ROWN
      FROM (SELECT product_id,
                   category,
                   product_name,
                   vol,
                   price,
                   CAST(stock AS int) AS stock,
                   date
            FROM stock_control
            WHERE 1 = 1) STOCK
      GROUP BY date,
               product_id,
               category,
               product_name,
               vol,
               price,
               stock,
               date
--HAVING STOCK != 0

) STOCK_2
--ORDER BY (MaxStock - MinStock) DESC
ORDER BY product_id,
         date ASC;
```

**Real image bellow from select * from mytable**

[image: Real Data]

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
Thank you for your comment!
This way is good or should I change something?

Comment: The derived table (alias STOCK) does nothing useful. `WHERE 1 = 1` Why? `CAST(stock AS int)` Why? The GROUP BY clause in derived table (alias STOCK_2) serves what purpose? The use of DISTINCT in the outer query serves what purpose? Quite frankly, this seems like you are throwing things into code without understanding what they do and without a clear goal. Add a script containing DDL, sample data, and your desired results based on that sample. I have no idea how 495 in first line is calculated since it does not appear to match your sample data.

Comment: @lptr Thank you very much!!
This was exactly what I needed, I just had to do some minor changes to match perfectly, would you mind explain what means this function "lag"?
Anyway I want to choose your answer as the right one :)

Comment: @SMor sorry, I was trying to solve this issue for two whole days by myself, and I changed the code a lot, so I was unable to post it as it was previously, but I'll try to let it cleaner for the next post times :)

Comment: @lptr Hello!
Sorry to bother again, I was trying to do the difference between each date interval.
Something like this:
('1ab7', '10/18/2022 20:10', 6003),    
('1ab7', '10/18/2022 21:30', 5514), [6003-5514] = 489
The logic is ALL the same, the only difference would be this detail, I tried to solve it by my self, but even with your code I couldnt.

Thank you again :)

Comment: `…as sumdiff,
stock - lead(stock, 1, stock) over(partition by product_id, grp order by date) as diff_current_next  from…`